# iOS: How to keep relationship sorted by a specific key?

Tags: ios, core-data

Have an `Event` entity, have an ordered relationship called `userEvents`. Need `userEvents` sorted by `dateCreated`. How? Always when a new `UserEvent` managed object is inserted, should I resort its entity's `userEvents`? Do you have better idea?

```
ue.event!.userEvents = NSOrderedSet(array: ue.event!.userEvents!.sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: true)]))
```

Any other way to insert `userEvent` to a specific position in `NSOrderedSet`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In Core Data all records are always inserted unordered.**

If the `Ordered` checkbox is checked the type of the relationship in the `NSManagedObject` subclass is `NSOrderedSet` rather than `NSSet`, no less, no more

Comment: Yes, ordered checkbox is set. Guess need "manually" sort relationship, right?